# Is changing the "main" property in bower.json considered a breaking change?

Tags: javascript, bower, semantic-versioning

Let's say I maintain a library called `foo`.

Currently, it's at version `1.0.0`. Its `bower.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/foo.js",
  // ...
}
```

I want to move `foo.js` out of the `dist/` folder and to the top level. I move `dist/foo.js` to `foo.js` and update my `bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main": "foo.js",
  // ...
}
```

Is this considered a breaking change? In other words, could someone using my library update and be including the incorrect file?

(I'm concerned the answer to this is "yes"—someone could be including files straight from `bower_components`.)

Comment: I don't think so, unless you documented including your scripts straight from `bower_components` as your public API. Which you didn't, right?

Comment: @Bergi I didn't, but I would expect that _somebody_ included it that way.

Comment: Well, sure, but everyone using a private API is responsible himself for broken things. This is clearly unintended usage, isn't it? Then don't worry.